# Swift Core Data : Error duringNSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent

Tags: controller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update with userInfo (null)

In my app -
I have a table view. The table view has two sections. The section is determined using a transient property in core data entity like this -

```
@objc var section: String?{
   return event < Date() ? "before" : "after"
}
```

The app is supposed to work like this:

1. The table view controller allows delete/cancel with cell swipe. When an item is deleted from the `fetchedResults` controller triggering the delegate methods, I delete the item in  **performBatchUpdates**. This works fine for inserts and deletes.
2. When the user selects a row it segues to a collection view. The view scrolls to the selected item (the item spans the entire view) in `collectionView`. The user can scroll back and forth between the various cell items. Items can be deleted from the collection View. I use **performBatchUpdates** here too, to delete the items in the delegate methods. This also works fine.
3. The problem occurs after I segue back from the collection view to the table View and only if I happen to delete items in the collection View and get back to the tableView.

a) If I insert items - no problems.

b) If I delete **rows** from a section that is the same section as the one I deleted **items** in the collection view.It works fine.

c) The above error shows up only when I try to delete an item from the other section (section 0 or 1) i.e. the one I did not delete from earlier in the `collectionView`.

#### Example -  In Table View

**Section 0 **

Item A
Item B

**Section 1**

Item C
Item D

If I delete **Item A** while in collection view then come back to table view, I see the following ( which is correct)

#### Table View after deletion:

**Section 0**

Item B

**Section 1**

Item C
Item D

But when I attempt to delete  Item D or Item C. The controller thinks I am trying to delete Items in section 0!

But if I delete Item B first in section 0, no issues.

If delete Item C and D  in section 1 after deleting item B  in section 0 - no issues.

I tried to debug by printing the `indexPaths` when deleting from core data (Fetched results controller) and also in `didChangeObject`, `didChangeSection` etc when it gets triggered. It prints the correct row and section I am attempting to remove. I am at my wit's end trying to fix the problem. Has anyone faced a similar issue and have a solution?

My `tableViewController`

```
var deleteMode:Bool = false

lazy var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<Event> in
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Event")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"eventDate",ascending:false)]
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"contact.name = %@", self.)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath:"section", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController as! NSFetchedResultsController<Event>
}()
```

`viewDidLoad` in the `tableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    //Load data
    do{
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    }catch let error{
        print("\(String(describing: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier)):\(error)")
    }
    
    // Other code
}

 @IBAction func unwindToEvents(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    do{
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        
    }catch let error{
        print("\(String(describing: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier)):\(error)")
    }
    eventsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

NSFetched Results controller and `tableView` delegate methods

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 
    let count = fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    
   // some other code...

    return count
}//end of numberOfSections

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  
        guard let count = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects else{
            return 0
        }
        return count
    }
}//end of numberOfRowsInSection

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let eventCell = eventsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: storyBoard.eventCell, for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
        eventCell.event = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as Event
        return eventCell
    }
}//end of cellForRowAt

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.currentEventIndex = indexPath
        let event = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: storyBoard.showEventDetail, sender: event)
    }
}//end of tableView didSelectRowAt


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            // delete item at indexPath
            let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(event)
            do{
                self.deleteMode = true
                try self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.save()
            }catch let error as NSError{
                 print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        let cancel = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Cancel") { (action, indexPath) in
            //cancel swipe action
        }
        cancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        
        return [delete,cancel]
}//end of editActionsForRowAt


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
}//end of canEditRowAt


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        guard let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else {
            return " "
        }
        return sectionInfo.name //which will be the sectionNameKeyPath we provided earlier.
    }


//MARK: NSFecthedResultscontroller delegate methods

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
 
    switch type{
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete:
        let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index:sectionIndex) as IndexSet
     blockOps.append(BlockOperation(block:{
            self.eventsTableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, with: .automatic)
        }))
    default:
        break
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type{
        case .delete:
            print(indexPath!.row,indexPath!.section)
            blockOps.append(BlockOperation(block:{
                self.eventsTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
            }))
        default:
            break
        }
}//end of didChange anObject at

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    if self.deleteMode{//perform block op only for delete mode
        self.deleteMode = false
        eventsTableView.performBatchUpdates({
            for operation in blockOps{
                operation.start()
            }
        },completion: { (completion) in

        })
    }
}//end of controllerDidChangeContent
    
}//end of EventsViewController
```

The collection view:

```
var blockOps = [BlockOperation]()

lazy var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<Event> in
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Event")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"eventDate",ascending:false)]
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "section", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController as! NSFetchedResultsController<Event>
}()

//Other code .........

@IBAction func didTapDeleteEvent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentItemIndex =  eventDetailCollection.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first
    if let indexPath = currentItemIndex{
        let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        
        self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(event)
        do{
            self.deleteMode = true
            try self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.save()
        }catch let error as NSError{
           print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}//end of didTapDelete



//The delegate methods

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type{
    case .delete:
        blockOps.append(BlockOperation(block:{
            self.eventDetailCollection.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])
        }))
    default:
        break
    }
}//end of didChange anObject at

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type{
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete:
        let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index:sectionIndex) as IndexSet
        blockOps.append(BlockOperation(block:{
            self.eventDetailCollection.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet)
        }))
    default:
        break
    }
}//end didChange SectionInfo

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    if self.deleteMode{//perform block op only in delete mode
        self.deleteMode = false
        eventDetailCollection.performBatchUpdates({
            for operation in blockOps{
                operation.start()
            }
        },completion: { (completion) in
            if let count = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count {
                if count < 1{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailToEvents", sender: self)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}//end of controllerDidChangeContent
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in my code. I am still very new with programming and Swift, but here is the code I have for delete with swipe from a tableview. Perhaps this can help with your code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard editingStyle == .delete else {
        return
    }

    // Fetch
    let inventory = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    // MARK: Delete
    // tells managed object cotext to delete the selected object
    fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(inventory)

    // goes to the data store and performs the action
    try? fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.save()

    // refetches the new data store
    try? fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

    // reloads data to the tableview
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Phyllis, I did initially try to delete from commit editingStyle method but that causes other errors ( happens when all rows from a section get deleted and the section itself needs to be removed). Switching to Delete in perform batch updates prevents those errors. Thanks anyways.